# Handle nulls inside the collect_set in Spark/Scala

Tags: scala, apache-spark

I have the below snippet which returns me nulls in the output as shown in the table

```scala
val customerAccountDS: Dataset[CustomerAccountOutput] = customerDS
    .join(accountDS, customerDS("customerId") === accountDS("customerId"), "left_outer")
    .groupBy(customerDS.col("customerId"), customerDS.col("forename"), customerDS.col("surname"))
    .agg(
      coalesce(collect_set(struct(accountDS.col("customerId"), accountDS.col("accountId"),
        accountDS.col("balance"))), array()).alias("accounts")

Output:

CustomerID       forename             Surname            accounts
112         A                     B                 [{null, null, null}]
```

How to replace nulls with a blank array as [].

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If `accounts` column has null value in `customerId` (or all values are null), column can replaced with empty array, with the same structure:

```
case class CustomerAccount(customerId: String, accountId: String, balance: Double)

.agg(...)
.withColumn("accounts",
      when($"accounts".getItem(0).getItem("customerId").isNull, typedLit(Array.empty[CustomerAccount]))
    .otherwise($"accounts")
)
```

Or you can map over `Dataset[CustomerAccountOutput]`, with replacing null arrays with `CustomerAccountOutput` copy constructor.